# Fast way to select all the elements of a list of strings, which contain at least a substring from another list

Tags: python, pandas, regex, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings like this:

```
samples = ['2345_234_1.0_1.35_001', '0345_123_2.09_1.3_003', ...]
```

The list can be quite long (up to 10^6 elements in the worst case). I have another list containing some substrings:

```
matches = ['7895_001', '3458_669', '0345_123', ...]
```

I would like to create a list `matched_samples` which contains only the elements of `samples` which contain one or more element of `matches`. For example, `samples[1]` ends up in `matched_samples` because `matches[3]` is a substring of `samples[1]`. I could do something like this:

```
matched_samples = [s for s in samples if any(xs in s for xs in matches)]
```

However, this looks like a double for loop, so it's not going to be fast. Is there any alternative? If `samples` was a `pandas` dataframe, I could simply do:

```
matches_regex = '|'.join(matches)
matched_samples = samples[samples['sample'].str.contains(matches_regex)]
```

Is there a similarly fast alternative with lists?

Comment: @TomKarzes, "If there are a lot of strings in matches" - and what if `matches` contains thousands of items? It won't be  efficient to go with regex  due to huge backtracking

Comment: In the general case where the strings could be anything and not follow any expected regularity, I do not think its possible to do better than an O2 operation. To make it faster you have to exploit something you expect to usually be the case about the particular strings.

Comment: @TomKarzes, *simple union of strings* - you've confused set operations and the way how regex works

Comment: @TomKarzes, you should read about regex backtracking

Comment: @TomKarzes, if you equate "automata theory" and "regex backtracking on partial matches in alternation groups" - you should definitely read about regex in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing as in your pandas example.

```
import re

samples = ['2345_234_1.0_1.35_001', '0345_123_2.09_1.3_003']
matches = ['7895_001', '3458_669', '0345_123']

pattern = re.compile(f"""{"|".join(re.escape(m) for m in matches)}""")
```

```
>>> [ s for s in samples if pattern.search(s) ]
['0345_123_2.09_1.3_003']
```

If there are no newlines in your samples - you could turn also turn that into a string and use `.findall()` with `(?:).*` around the pattern.

Not sure if that would make a difference speed-wise.

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(f"""(?:{"|".join(re.escape(m) for m in matches)}).*""")
>>> pattern
re.compile(r'(?:7895_001|3458_669|0345_123).*', re.UNICODE)
>>> pattern.findall("\n".join(samples))
['0345_123_2.09_1.3_003']
```

Answer (score -1):

> this looks like a double for loop, so it's not going to be fast.

Firstly please become aware of *premature optimization* which is generally considered not desired. In this case you should answer question: is it fast enough for your use case?

Secondly, observe that

```
matched_samples = [s for s in samples if any(xs in s for xs in matches)]
```

is greatly dependent at your data. Worst case is if there is not single match, as it result in `len(samples)*len(matches)` of is substring checks, best case is if first element of `matches` is substring of every element of `samples` as you will then got `len(samples)` of is substring checks, as `any` cease futher processing after find 1st truth-y value. Observe that this mean processing time does depend at matches ordering.